# Issue when creating lots of MediaPlayers

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating an app where the user can customize an (mp4 video) animation (think about something you might see at a bowling alley). During regular use, there could be anywhere from 20-100 of these animations loaded. My program will receive input from an external source, and depending on the input, one of these animations will need to be played *very* quickly, we're talking less than a tenth of a second here...

I'm using JavaFX's `MediaPlayer` to accomplish this. To prevent buffering times, I've decided to have an entire `MediaPlayer` associated with every animation. However, this causes problems when approaching ~20 players.

Although I don't need audio (in fact, I set each player to mute upon creation), JavaFX is allocating sound resources from the OS (which you can see in the OS mixer, one slider for every player). When I approach the mentioned ~20 players being created, I will get an exception thrown from the player (stored in `getException()`) as follows:

```
MediaException: PLAYBACK_HALTED : Could not open audio device for playback.
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.haltException(MediaException.java:150)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer$_PlayerStateListener.lambda$onHalt$7(MediaPlayer.java:2557)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

(this error was caused on Ubuntu 16.10, haven't tested on other platforms)

I'm guessing this is caused by the quantity of MediaPlayers allocated and the OS is rejecting it for some reason.

I'm reluctant to use GIFs due to their quality loss. I suppose another option could be flipping between `ImageView`s very fast, but this would require the user to split up each frame.

Anyways, I'm looking for suggestions. Maybe a potential fix for this error? Is there some alternative that would work better? Thanks!

Comment: Did you measure the time it takes to start playback when using a single MediaPlayer? This sounds like a premature optimization.

Comment: Yes, it sometimes takes up to half a second. This is file I/O and networking time I assume.

Comment: How does it behave if you only deal with local files? I can imagine that downloading all the media first could solve the issue with delay.

Comment: The files are local, but they are still too slow to load.

Comment: I'd say file a bug report, because you are using it like it is supposed to be used, i.e. one MediaView, multiple MediaPlayers for the individual media. If there is only one MediaView present, there really should only be one OS control available for its volume, and not as many as there are MediaPlayers.

Comment: For the time being, you could have ~19 active players, so that they are not rejected by the OS, and keep the most used media in there. _better than nothing_

Comment: @Matthias Well you can play audio (and video) files without a `MediaView`, but you will only hear the audio.

Comment: Here's the bug report: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8173619